# Require JS Text Plugin Dynamic Parameter Issues

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am trying to write a function that I can use to pull my templates with Require and its text plugin.

I want to be able to call `template('modules', 'login');` and have it load the desired template.

```
define(function(require) {
    return function(path, file) {
        return require('lib/text!templates/ + path + '/' + file + '.html');
    }
});
```

So my code throws an error but if I hard code the path like this

`require(lib/text!templates/modules/login.html)`

It works the way I want. I've tried different variations of using parameters from a function to create the string parameter for require with mixed results and logged the strings that are getting passed just to make sure they are the same. Any ideas?

Heres the error I'm getting back
`Uncaught Error: Module name "lib/text!templates/modules/profile.html" has not been loaded yet for context: _`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want to do but not with a *synchronous* function.

When you use `require(...)` with a single argument which is a string, you are relying on RequireJS' support for the CommonJS way of requiring modules. Let's suppose you put a string literal in you `require(...)` call, which you said works:

```
define(function(require) {
    return function(path, file) {
        return require('lib/text!templates/modules/login.html');
    }
});
```

Behind the scenes, RequireJS transforms the code above into something like this:

```
define(['require', 'lib/text!templates/modules/login.html'], function(require) {
    return function(path, file) {
        return require('lib/text!templates/modules/login.html');
    }
});
```

Note the added dependencies to the `define` call. By the time `require` executes, the module you are requiring has already been loaded, and everything is fine. The function you return as your module value *can* return the value of `'lib/text!templates/modules/login.html'` synchronously.

The problem is that this process cannot work if the `require(...)` call contains **anything else than a string literal**. If you set `var x = 'lib/text!templates/modules/login.html'` and then do `require(x)`, *it won't work!* RequireJS will not be able to perform the transformation like I've shown above and when `require(...)` executes, the module that it wants to load has not been loaded yet, and it fails. It's just a limitation of RequireJS. The form of `require(...)` with a string as sole argument (rather than a list of modules and a callback) exists *solely* to support the CommonJS way of loading modules. However, this form of `require` *fails* if the module required is not already loaded. This is why RequireJS transforms the modules in which such call appears so that the modules requires are added to the list of dependencies of the module. But it can perform this transformation *only* for `require(...)` calls that have a single argument which is a string literal. Nothing else will do.

What you *can* do is:

```
define(function(require) {
    return function(path, file, cb) {
        require(['lib/text!templates/' + path + '/' + file + '.html'], cb);
    }
});
```

The value returned by the module is an *asynchronous* function, which will call the callback passed as `cb` with the value of the template.